# Reading twitter public stream

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm trying to read the twitter public stream, I have used the twitter4j Java Library to do this.

The examples given in [Sample Codes](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) section "Streaming API" show that it should be coded like below

```
StatusListener listener = new MyStatusListener();
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(listener).getInstance();
```

Here the MyStatusListener implements the StatusListener interface. But I get error when creating the TwitterStreamFactory object (Cannot Resolve Constructor TwitterStreamFactory(twitter4j.Listener)), Have anyone come across this problem. Please comment any ideas

Comment: add stack trace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `TwitterStreamFactory` incorrectly.

try this:

```
StatusListener listener = new MyStatusListener();
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
twitterStream.addListenter(listener);
```

you will also need to add a `FilterQuery` to the `twitterStream` instance

Comment: yeagh that worked :) Thank you verry much. I was just refering to the sample code given in twitter4j site and seems it's wrong.